# The antichain of P(B)

Tags: number-theory, set-theory

Given a set **B** the set of all subsets of **B** labeled $\mathbf P(B)$ is made up of all the combinations of the elements of **B** The subset **A** of $\mathbf P(B)$ is an *antichain* if no element of **A** is a subset of any other element of **A**.

Does $\mathbf P(B)$ contain a countable number of antichains for finite sets **B**, with *b elements*? What about for open intervals $(0,1) \in \Bbb R$? For all the elements of a countably infinite set such as Q?

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. I understand the definitions (despite the terrible inconsistency of the choice of font zigzagging between italics, boldface, and blackboard bold); I don't fully understand the question.

Comment: If a set is finite, then its power set has only finitely many antichains.  If a set is infinite, then its power set has uncountably many antichains. In no case does a power set have exactly a countable infinity of antichains. (Your definition of "antichain" should say that no element of the antichain is a subset of any *other* element of that antichain.)

Comment: Why not? What if I wanted the set such that the antichain of its power set, has exactly N infinite elements? surely there must be something in all of the infinite realms of possibility that would fit the bill?